# Does Debian's "apt-get install" command follow "recommends" links recursively?

Tags: debian, apt-get, recursive

Debian's `apt-get install` command is documented as following `recommends` links by default.  It also follows `depends` links, presumably in a recursive fashion. However, I haven't been able to find out if it also follows `recommends` links recursively.

For example, let's say that I run `apt-get install foo` and that `foo` depends on or recommends `bar`.  I would expect `apt-get` to install `bar` and all of its dependencies.  However, I don't know whether it would also install bar's recommended packages, etc.  Can someone please clarify this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, yes: both `APT::Install-Recommends` *apt.conf* option and `--install-recommends` command-line option are "global" (i.e. they will be applied to recursive dependencies too).

Just checked that empirically and looked at the *apt* source code: *apt* dependency solver seems to apply the `follow_recommends` option recursively.